# process builder and time based workflows

Tags: process-builder

I need to call a external webservice to update a field, so i got the process builder to call an apex method with invocable type which is all good.

But after implementing I noticed that the external webservice calls timeouts occasionally so it goes more than a minute, unfortunately those are legacy systems so can't do much over it.

Coming to question is there any way I can use process builder to retry if the apex action timesout? The only way I can think of is to use a schedule job to get those records and run it separately.

Comment: Did you try to update the apex timeout duration? You can extend it to upto 2 minutes.

Comment: What happens if the webservice times out? If the record is updated with an error message, you could run a process based on that.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty well we don't want to increase timeouts since these web services are so old and we don't have SF resources to hang on it.

Comment: @martin when the update does fail we don't update the field and leave it blank. We can't add a value to it since it will trigger other workflows based on the values.

Comment: If the logic on that record is getting too complex, you could consider creating a child object "Callout Error", and insert a record whenever a webservice fails.